# Kafka - Not able to list new consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka

I am creating consumer groups using `Kafka-console-consumer.sh`.

If I create a old consumer group with zookeeper then I can see the consumer group is created when I list consumers.

**Old Consumer Group**

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181  --security-protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT  --topic test --consumer-property group.id=old_consumer_group
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --zookeeper d9lcwphd1m1.labcorp.ad.ctc:2181
```

However, When I create a new consumer group. I can't see that in the list.

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh  --bootstrap-server localhost:6667  --security-protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT  --topic test --consumer-property group.id=new_consumer_group
```

**List shows empty**

```
gaurang.shah@hadoop_dev]$ kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:6667 --security-protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT --list
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

[2019-03-05 15:07:45,182] WARN [Principal=gaurang.shah@abc.com]: TGT renewal thread has been interrupted and will exit. (org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin)
```

I checked the ACL and found this, not sure if it applies to only OLD group or both?

```
 Current ACLs for resource `Group:*`:
        User:* has Allow permission for operations: All from hosts: *
        User:Alice has Allow permission for operations: All from hosts: *
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using `1.0.0`